# Como criar .BAT para renomear vários arquivos em várias pastas inserindo data e hora de criação?

Tags: batch

Alguém sabe como criar `.bat` para renomear vários arquivos em várias pastas inserindo data e hora de criação, e não a data atual?

Exemplo:

```
Nome                        Data e hora de Criação

SCP Dados.mdb               03/06/2016 10:26
```

Depois de renomear é para ficar assim:

```
Nome                        Data e hora de Criação

SCP Dados030616-1026.mdb    03/06/2016 10:26
```

Apagando qualquer caractere antes e depois do nome criado deixando a extensão `.mdb` "`<-SCP Dados030616-1026->.mdb`"

Já fiz isso:

```
@echo   Renomeando arquivo SCP Dados.mdb da BAHIA (BKP Manha)

dir \\S1WKSPCRCI\B$\CIBackups\Backup_BA\"SCP Dados.mdb" [AQUI ME MOSTRA A DATA]

set /p dt_arq_ba= Digite a DATA de Criacao do Arquivo da BAHIA: [AQUI INSIRO A DATA]

ren \\S1WKSPCRCI\B$\CIBackups\Backup_BA\SCP?Dados.mdb "SCP Dados%dt_arq_ba%.mdb" [AQUI ME DA O ARQUIVO RENOMEADO]
```

Está funcionando, mais só renomeia manualmente de um por um, queria automatizar com a data de criação do arquivo.

Comment: [**Edite**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/146322/edit) a pergunta e coloque o que você já fez.

Comment: Estou aguardando sugestões, obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Precisa ser em .bat mesmo ?

Comment: Veja se esta resposta ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079757/rename-file-with-creation-date-time-in-windows-batch

Comment: Você vai precisar fazer um loop no diretório raiz utilizando o comando "for" combinando com o comando "/D". De uma lida neste artigo:https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

Answer (score 1):

**:: 1)** Liste os arquivos e redirecione a saída para 
 **`"%temp%\_file_origem.txt"`**

**:: 2)** Use um loop for para obter os caminhos e portar para o comando **`WMIC "\"="\\"`**

**:: 3)** Use outro loop for para obter a data de criação e salvar numa variável para renomear.

**:: 4)** Ajuste o layout de saída da data da criação para o formato pretendido:

**:: 5)** Setar o novo nome de arquivo e renomear retirando os caracteres indesejáveis:

---

- **Obs.: Sobre a linha:** 
   **<kbd>`echo/ ren "!_file_!" "SCP Dados!_date_create!.mdb"  && timeout /t 3 2>nul >nul`</kbd>**

  > **Adicionada** apenas para **debug**, **remover** após **verificar** funcionamento.

---

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo/  Renomeando arquivo SCP Dados.mdb da BAHIA ^(BKP Manha^)

rem  :: 1 ::
for %%i in (target origem) do echo/>"%temp%\_file_%%i.txt"
dir /s /b /a-d "\\S1WKSPCRCI\B$\CIBackups\Backup_BA\*.mdb" >>"%temp%\_file_origen.txt">>"%temp%\_file_origem.txt"

rem :: 2 ::
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('type "%temp%\_file_origem.txt"') do ( 
     for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%I in ('dir /w /b "%%~i"') do set "_file_=%%~fI"&& call :_rename
     )  
goto :eof 

rem :: 3 ::
:_rename
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%r in ('wmic datafile where name^='!_file_:\^=\\!' get "creationdate" ^| findstr /v "CreationDate"') do ( 

rem :: 4 ::                            
     set "_date_=%%r"
     set _date_create=!_date_:~6,2!!_date_:~4,2!!_date_:~2,2!-!_date_:~8,2!!_date_:~10,2!

rem :: 5 ::  
     echo/ ren "!_file_!" "SCP Dados!_date_create!.mdb"  && timeout /t 3 2>nul >nul 
     for %%d in (file date_create) do set _%%d=<nul
     exit /b
    )
```

Comment: Foi bloqueada pelo excesso de postagens (já removidas) usando indevidamente o campo de respostas. Quando isto ocorre com frequência é sinal de que a pergunta tende a "atrair" demais usuários casuais que não compreendem o funcionamento do site. Aproveitando, para dúvidas como essa, temos o [Site Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) que é "o site para dúvidas sobre o site"